# jooq - exclude id field when inserting from POJO

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

Is there anyway to insert a new record into a PostgreSQL database with Jooq straight from a POJO which extends a general identity class that has an id field without including the id in the insert statement?

An example POJO:

```
@Data
public abstract class PersistenceIdentity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 7, insertable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    public abstract Table<R> getJooqTable();
}

@Data
public class SocialNetwork extends PersistenceIdentity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Override
    public Table<SocialNetworkRecord> getJooqTable() {
        return Tables.SOCIAL_NETWORK;
    }

}
```

The PostgreSQL schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE "social_network" (
    id              SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_date    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
    name            TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

My code to persist the POJO:

```
public <T extends PersistenceIdentity> T insertRecord(T record) {
    Record newRecord = db.newRecord(record.getJooqTable(), record);
    if (newRecord instanceof UpdatableRecord) {
        ((UpdatableRecord) newRecord).store();
    }

    return newRecord.into(record);
}
```

I realize I'm probably doing what Jooq really wasn't meant for (i.e. using generic types), however that (appears) to work just fine.

The problem is, Jooq includes the id in the insert statement and I then, of course, get a null value constraint.  I don't want it inserted when it's a new record, however I do want it included when it returns the record (after inserting), when updating and also in select statements.

I can't simply exclude the id because I need it later on to easily get around some of the @OneToMany / @ManyToOne limitations.

And I would rather not have to insert the specific values for each POJO (that's why we annotated with @Column).

Does Jooq not honor the @Id or the insertable = false parameter in @Column?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

**EDIT 1**
Per request, below is the relevant snippet from the jOOQ generated table object.  I'm not sure if this is correct or not for what I'm trying to do (i.e. allow the database to generate the ID), but I would think `nextval('social_network_id_seq'::regclass)` would accomplish that.

```
@Generated(
    value = {
        "http://www.jooq.org",
        "jOOQ version:3.9.1"
    },
    comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ"
)
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class SocialNetwork extends TableImpl<SocialNetworkRecord> {

    /**
     * The column <code>public.social_network.id</code>.
     */
    public final TableField<SocialNetworkRecord, Integer> ID = createField("id", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.INTEGER.defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("nextval('social_network_id_seq'::regclass)", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.INTEGER)), this, "");

}
```

Also, we use the `mvn jooq-codegen:generate -Djooq.generator.name=org.jooq.util.XMLGenerator` to generate the XML schema and then generate the the jOOQ table objects from that XML config.  The thinking is we can push the XML config to github and all builds can simply regenerate the table objects from that.

Here is the XML:

```
<column>
    <table_catalog></table_catalog>
    <table_schema>public</table_schema>
    <table_name>social_network</table_name>
    <column_name>id</column_name>
    <data_type>integer</data_type>
    <character_maximum_length>0</character_maximum_length>
    <numeric_precision>32</numeric_precision>
    <numeric_scale>0</numeric_scale>
    <ordinal_position>1</ordinal_position>
    <column_default>nextval('social_network_id_seq'::regclass)</column_default>
</column>
<table_constraint>
    <constraint_catalog></constraint_catalog>
    <constraint_schema>public</constraint_schema>
    <constraint_name>social_network_pkey</constraint_name>
    <constraint_type>PRIMARY KEY</constraint_type>
    <table_catalog></table_catalog>
    <table_schema>public</table_schema>
    <table_name>social_network</table_name>
</table_constraint>
<table_constraint>
    <constraint_catalog></constraint_catalog>
    <constraint_schema>public</constraint_schema>
    <constraint_name>2200_17431_1_not_null</constraint_name>
    <constraint_type>CHECK</constraint_type>
    <table_catalog></table_catalog>
    <table_schema>public</table_schema>
    <table_name>social_network</table_name>
</table_constraint>
<table_constraint>
    <constraint_catalog></constraint_catalog>
    <constraint_schema>public</constraint_schema>
    <constraint_name>2200_17431_3_not_null</constraint_name>
    <constraint_type>CHECK</constraint_type>
    <table_catalog></table_catalog>
    <table_schema>public</table_schema>
    <table_name>social_network</table_name>
</table_constraint>
<key_column_usage>
    <column_name>id</column_name>
    <constraint_catalog></constraint_catalog>
    <constraint_schema>public</constraint_schema>
    <constraint_name>social_network_pkey</constraint_name>
    <ordinal_position>0</ordinal_position>
    <table_catalog></table_catalog>
    <table_schema>public</table_schema>
    <table_name>social_network</table_name>
</key_column_usage>
```

**EDIT 2** 
My SocialNetwork jOOQ-generated table object does not have a `getIdentity()` method, however it does have a `getPrimaryKey()` method and if it helps, my SocialNetworkRecord class has two Constructors:

```
public SocialNetworkRecord() {
    super(SocialNetwork.SOCIAL_NETWORK);
}

/**
 * Create a detached, initialised SocialNetworkRecord
 */
public SocialNetworkRecord(Integer id, Timestamp createdDate, String name) {
    super(SocialNetwork.SOCIAL_NETWORK);

    set(0, id);
    set(1, createdDate);
    set(2, name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way jOOQ works, there are two elements worth explaining:

#### Step 1: `Record.from(Object)`:

```java
Record newRecord = db.newRecord(record.getJooqTable(), record);
```

This call is convenience for this:

```java
Record newRecord = db.newRecord(record.getJooqTable());
newRecord.from(record);
```

And the [`Record.from(Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#from-java.lang.Object-) will copy all values from the `record` to the `newRecord` by using [`Record.set(Field, Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#set-org.jooq.Field-T-), which again sets the record's internal [`Record.changed(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#changed-org.jooq.Field-) flag.

#### Step 2: `UpdatableRecord.store()`

Your call to:

```java
((UpdatableRecord) newRecord).store();
```

Will take all `changed()` fields into consideration for the relevant `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement that is executed. The rationale here is that people sometimes want to set the primary key value explicitly, and not let an identity generate the value for them. Even if an identity is present on the primary key, it may sometimes be desireable to override its value. SQL standard databases (e.g. Oracle 12c) thus support two ways of specifying an identity:

```sql
-- This can be overridden
GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY

-- This can never be overridden
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

(MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` or PostgreSQL's `SERIAL` type work the same way)

jOOQ assumes `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` here. The only exception to the above behaviour is when the identity column is `NOT NULL` and the `Record` value for the identity is `null` and jOOQ's meta model is aware of both:

```
- `NOT NULL` constraint
- `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`
```

Then, jOOQ will omit considering the identity value for insertion / update.

#### Bug in 3.9.2 and less:

Note that up until jOOQ version 3.9.2, there was a bug / missing feature in the `XMLGenerator` that produces the XML file you're importing: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6141. This bug resulted in no identity information being generated.

#### Workaround 1: If you cannot influence the jOOQ meta model

If, for some reason, you cannot get the jOOQ meta model to reflect your `NOT NULL` constraint and your `DEFAULT` clause, you could work around this limitation by resetting the value of the identity right after your `Record.from(Object)` call using [`Record.reset(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#reset-org.jooq.Field-):

```java
Record newRecord = db.newRecord(record.getJooqTable(), record);
newRecord.reset(identityColumn);
((UpdatableRecord) newRecord).store();
```

#### Workaround 2: Generate a synthetic identity

The code generator has a feature to generate [synthetic identities](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-synthetic-identities/). For instance, if all your identity columns are called `ID`, you could write this:

```xml
<!-- fully qualified -->
<syntheticIdentities>.*?\.ID</syntheticIdentities>
```

Or this:

```xml
<!-- unqualified -->
<syntheticIdentities>ID</syntheticIdentities>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Forgive me, but I've already set the identity column as NOT NULL and the Record value for the identity is null (hence the null constraint violation).  jOOQ's meta model should be aware of both; the Table objects were generated based on the xml scheme which was generated from the live database.  Unless there is something I'm missing?

Comment: @Brooks: Can you post that generated table object in your question? (at least the identity column definition). What "XML scheme" do you mean?

Comment: I edited the original question with those details.  I didn't see any Id annotations for the identity column in the table object but I'm not sure what it's supposed to have.  It does have the identity generation instruction though.

Comment: @Brooks: Thank you very much for the additional info. The column is generated correctly, but is it also returned as an identity in the table's `getIdentity()` method?
In any case, I've opened a bug report for this, in case this can be shown as a bug related to the XMLGenerator: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6141

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question about returning an identity in the getIdentity() method. I'm not actually calling that method.  Should I be?  Do you want me to switch over to the github bug report for further discussion?

Comment: Does the code generator generate an `getIdentity()` method in your `SocialNetwork` class?

Comment: No, I don't see a getIdentity method anywhere and I did a project-wide search.  It does have a `getPrimaryKey()` method and the SocialNetworkRecord class has two Constructors.  They are above in the question.

Comment: OK, I see. I'll try reproducing, then. It's probably a bug.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Do you think this is specific to 3.9.0?  I'm just curious how this hasn't happened to anyone else yet...?  I know there are a few ways to create the Record for insert, i.e. I can set the values individually.  So am I doing it in a non-recommended way?  Anyways, for now I will try the reset method you suggested and thanks again!

Comment: In fact, this kind of question has been asked about a dozen of times on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user) :) It's just that usually, people use the "ordinary" code generator, not the XML-based one, which is not used as often, as it still doesn't support a variety of features (including stored procedures, for instance).

Comment: Aahhh I'll need to get on the list.  By "ordinary" code generator, you mean the object generator direct from the database?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "ordinary". And gaaah, I see the problem now: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/version-3.9.2/jOOQ-codegen/src/main/java/org/jooq/util/XMLGenerator.java#L125. :-/ I've updated the GitHub issue. So, another workaround would be to put the some value for the `<identityGeneration>some_value</identityGeneration>` in the XML file for each identity column

Comment: I'll check it out and report back on the github issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to use the synthetic identity code generator configuration: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-synthetic-identities